# How do I query using ODATA for the existence of a relationship between two entities?

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

Is there a way to write an ODATA query (i.e., using an ODATA URL) that tests for the existance of a relationship between two entity instances?

Imagine I have two entity types in an ODATA service: Person and Project.  Imagine I've defined a many-to-many relationhip between them (something like Person owns Project).  I have the primary key (ID) of each of a Person and a Project and want to know if the Person owns the Project.

I can figure out, given a Person, how to get all the Projects owned by that person but this will, in the general case, return way more data than I want (and have perf problems in other similar scenarios).  Can I query for the relationship itself somehow?

My server is using WCF and Entity Framework 4.0 on ASP.NET.  My client is HTML and jquery running in a browser.

If there's no way to write the relationship query, is there a best practice for something like this to extend the ODATA service with a custom method to test this?

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply call something like: `ODataService.svc/Persons(1)/Projects(5)`. This will try to return `Project` with Id=5 related to `Person` with Id=2 because `Persons` in this case is the entity set and `Projects` is the navigation property on the `Person` entity. If the relation exists you will get the record. If it doesn't exists you will get something like *Resource not found*.

Comment: Oh, cool.  I didn't realize you could provide a key to a navigation property.  I'll try that.